# Minimum value - with cube root of unity

Tags: complex-numbers

**Question:**

> If $a,b,c$ are integers that are not all equal and $w$ is a cube root of unity ($w\neq1$), then find the minimum value of $$|a + bw + cw^2|$$

I tried to use the concept of AM $\geq$ GM.

$$|a + bw + cw^2| \geq 3(abwcw^2)^{1/3}$$
 $$|a + bw + cw^2| \geq 3(abc)^{1/3}$$

Well the minimum value of RHS is obviously 0, when either a, b, or c is equal to zero. So, the minimum value of LHS should be zero. However, that would be only when $a = b = c = 0$. But we know that not all of them are equal. So... what to do?

Comment: @G-man Aha...... So... what should I do?

Comment: @Gummybears You should use $w^2=-w-1$

Comment: @G-man That would take quite a while... No graphical method to do it?

Comment: Ewan: why is that true?

Comment: @EwanDelanoy I tried.... Didn't get me anywhere.

Comment: Why, calculate the values for (say) $0\le a,b,c\le3$, plot them on the complex plane, notice the pattern.

Comment: @IvanNeretin I don't think that's the best way to do it...

Comment: Neither do I. The best way is via algebraic manipulations. What I said was (probably) good for illustrative purposes, just to get a picture "what's going on" in your head.

Comment: Well played. He should be going on a rampage breaking stuff now, I think.

Comment: @mathreadler I'm thinking of doing it..... I don't think there's an intuitive solution to this problem.

Comment: Is it really a problem? You don't secretly enjoy it?

Comment: @mathreadler Enjoy what? A rampage?

Comment: The attention. All the subtle (and less subtle) attempts. Having to strengthen your mind to deal with problems.

Comment: @mathreadler I do.... but then eventually I get depressed that I can't solve a problem despite spending 4 hours on it.... And then leave all hope.

Comment: If things go too easy and painless you don't hone your skills enough. It may seem unfair or outright evil sometimes, but just try and think of it as maximizing your capacity. Becoming a stronger more stable person.

Comment: @mathreadler I guess.... It is the best way to learn.

Answer (score 1):

for $w=-(-1)^3$ or $(-1)^{2/3}$ the expression can be written as

$$
(1)\;\;\;\;\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2-ab-ac-bc}
$$
indeed
$$
|a+b w+ c w^2|=\sqrt{(a+b w+ c w^2)(a+b \bar w+ c \bar w^2)}
$$
use that $\bar w = w^2,\; \bar w^2 =w$ and $w+1/w=-1$ to simplify it to (1).

If the question is about minimization w.r.t. $a,b,c$ then take $a=b,\;c=a+1$ to get $1$. It cannot be smaller because 1) its square is integer 2) for it to be $0$ one must have $a=b=c$:

$$
a^2+b^2+c^2-ab-ac-bc = 0 \;\;\Rightarrow\;\;2c =\pm i\sqrt 3(a-b)+a+b\;\;\Rightarrow\;\;a=b\;\;\Rightarrow\;\;a=b=c
$$

Comment: The question is as is. Although it was a multiple choice question.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood the question at first. Now it should be ok.

Comment: Why can't c be less than 1? It can be 0.0000000000001 for all we know.

Comment: By "it" I mean expression (1) not c. But also c is integer so 0.000000001 is not good.

Comment: *facepalm*..... That I didn't notice... Otherwise the question becomes quite easy.

Comment: otherwise it will be even easier - there would be no minimum if $a,b,c$ were not integers you can indeed approach $0$ as close as you wish but never reach it.

Comment: That's exactly what I was wondering!

Answer (score 1):

Hint :  Show first that $|a+bw+cw^2|=|(a-c)+(b-c)w| \geq 2$ whenever $|b-c| >1$ (because then $(b-c)w$ will be too far away from the $x$-axis, because of its height). This leaves you with the cases $b-c=-1,0,1 \ldots $. You will see then that the minimum is $1$.

Comment: Not sure where the inequality with 2 came from?

Comment: @Gummybears It's obvious when you make a drawing. Try it. For example, a point of altitude $2$ is at a distance $ \geq 2$ from the $x$-axis

Comment: Sorry, but I just can't imagine what you're trying to say. And you started with 'show that the minimum is 1'. But how did you get that?

Comment: You don't know about graphical representation of complex numbers ?

Comment: I do. But not sure how I can use that here.

Comment: If you prefer a more computational version, putting $x=a-c$ and $y=b-c$, $x$ and $y$ are integers and you have $|a+bw+cx^2|=|x+yw|=|x+y(-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}i)|=(x-\frac{1}{2})^2+\frac{3y^2}{4} \geq \frac{3y^2}{4} \geq 3$ when $|y| > 1$.

Comment: Aha...... I see it better now... I was hoping for something more intuitive though. As complex numbers can usually be solved by intuition. Guess this problem, however, doesn't have such a solution.

Comment: There **IS** a geometric intuiton. Draw the axis, draw the point above it, then project the point on the $x$-axis, and look at the distances